# Group Chat Signal R with Web API

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, signalr-2

Below i have three table which is used for GroupChat,Firstly I am creating the group its all data wil be inserted into GroupTable,then on success of groupCreation i am calling **insertConnectionId** function which will call the **MapGroupConnectionId** on backend which generate the SignalR connection ID and insert into GroupTable using groupId and groupCreaterId, its working fine and i have Group Friends Table which consist of Friends ID,Now when any friend sent message to particular Group, i need to send the Message to all who are in that Particular Group through SignalR, i thought, i ll assign the groupConnectionID in group table to all the Members who are related to that Group then i can send message to that particular group which will be received by GroupFriends,My hub which works only for Hub.Client.ALL but not for other function, please guide me if i am doing it in wrong way,I am new to signalR

```
 //Group Table

 groupID   groupName groupImage  groupCreaterId groupConnectionId groupsignalrIsConnected
   1         dude       someurl        421       somestringID       TRUE
   2         god        someurl        444       somestringID       TRUE
   3         heaven     someurl        543       Null               FALSE
   4         hell       someurl        678       Null               FALSE


 //Group Friends Table

groupFriendsTabID   groupId groupFriendsId
      111              2    444
      112              3    678
      113              2    421
      114              4    444
      115              1    543
      116              4    421
      117              1    678
      118              2    543
      119              3    444


  //Group Message Table

  groupMesTabId groupId groupsenderId   groupMessage
         22             1   543             hello
         23             3   678             hi


 //My HUB
[HubName("groupChatHub")]
public class GroupChatHub : Hub
{
    GroupRepository group= new GroupRepository ();


    public void **MapGroupConnectionId**(long groupID,int groupCreatorId)
      {
       if (groupID != 0 && groupCreatorId!=0)
            {   
             CBG.MapGroupConnectionId(groupID, Context.ConnectionId);
              Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).configureUserSettings();}
             }

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
    public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
    {
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
    }
    public override Task OnReconnected()
    {
        return base.OnReconnected();
    }
}

  //My WEBAPI//
   public class GroupController : ApiControllerWithHub<GroupchatHub>
    {
        public IhttpActionResult InsertNewMessage(messageModel model)
        {
              //Here i am  inserting new message to Database using some    function it works fine//

            after success of inserting message i need to send that message  to groupmembers using signalr 

     //here i am fetching the connectionID through groupID from group table
      var connectionID=repository.getConnection(model.groupID)

           var messager = "11";
   Hub.Clients.All.getGroupChat(messager); // this works 

   Hub.Clients.clients(connectionID).getGroupChat(messager);this not working it except IList<string>

  Hub.Clients.Groups(groupName,ConnectionID).getGroupChat(messager); this is not  working
         }
   return ok(Model);
    }



 //MyClientEnd//

  var Grouphub

//this insertConnectionId is called once the group is created on the success  of group creation and SignalRconnectionstring is inserted in GroupTable 

function insertConnectionId(groupId,groupCreatorID)
 $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
    console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + $.connection.hub.id);
    console.log("Connected, transport = " +      $.connection.hub.transport.name);
    Grouphub.server.mapGroupConnectionId(groupID, groupCreatorID);
 });
 $.connection.hub.error(function (error) {
    console.log('SignalR error: ' + error)
 });

 });

 Grouphub = $.connection.groupChatHub
 Grouphub.client.getGroupChat = function (data) {
  alert("in");

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a similar project like and used it in different areas,

Check out this example it will help you :)

https://github.com/DenizGokce/SignalR

Comment: @thanks for your project it helped me,i just wanted to know, The method which i have used for  user to bind signalr connection string and store it in Database as above code,its good way to achieve it or if there is any better way let me know