# $.connection.chatHub getting undefined in signalR even after loading the scripts properly

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am trying to use `signalR` in an existing `MVC` application. I am loading the scripts in order. I can see the `jQuery` and hubs scripts in the browser network console. But, I am getting an error saying `chatHub` is undefined. 
Surprisingly, when I try to debug the code and put a break point on

```
proxies.chatHub = this.createHubProxy('chatHub');
```

and after that when I go to console and type `$.connectrion.chatHub` I can see all the properties of the object. But, when I end the debugging, the `$.connection` gets undefined and then nothing works.
Please help me with a solution. I have tried every link available for `signalR` and tried every possibility, but my problem seems to be different.
I am using `signalR-1.0.1.`

Comment: Checkout this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504667/group-chat-signal-r-with-web-api/41505473#41505473

Comment: The issue is with $.connection and nothing else. I am trying to debug but no luck as of now.

Answer (score 0):

If you made your signalr host different than your project than it cannot find this properly

```
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

So you need to specify like

```
<script src="http://localhost:{Your SignalR Host Port}/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

Also if you want to compare there is a fully working example in here. https://github.com/DenizGokce/SignalR

EDIT:

This is how signalr framework works you need to define a structure like OnlineClient in the hub and you need to bind those different connectionIds in the server side

```
public class OnlineClient{
      public Int SomeClientId; /*You Defined*/
      public List<String> ConnectionIds {get;set;}
}

public List<OnlineClient> _onlineClients = new List<OnlineClient>();
```

like this you need to manage your clients in the server side

Comment: Did you check the project you might find something helpful

Comment: The problem is that I have two layouts on which I am using the signalR chatbox. One of them is a third party reporting app and on that it is causing the undefined error. The logic for chatapp is a shared resource and it works on one layout and doesn't work on the other.

Comment: each layout must connect individually if you consider each layout as webclient for signalr server than these layouts must have different clientId or connectionId could that be the problem? i dont know if you are trying to connect them from same clientId.

Comment: how do I achieve this?

Comment: I debugged and found out that the client id and tokens being generated are different on these layouts. I don't know why as soon as I end the debugging the $.connection becomes undefined.

Comment: This is how signalr framework works you need to define a structure like OnlineClient in the hub and you need to bind those different connectionIds in the server side 

public class OnlineClient{
      public Int SomeClientId; /*You Defined*/
      public List<String> ConnectiionIds {get;set;}
}

public List<OnlineClient> _onlineClients = new List<OnlineClient>();

like this you need to manage your clients in the server side

Comment: I debugged the whole code and found that $.connection.chatHub works fine until the jquery.js loading at the end of it.