# Send signalr notification from web api to application site

Tags: c#, signalr

I have Web API application in which I need to send notification using SignalR Hub to application site.

**Web api**

```
HubConnection connection = new HubConnection("http://localhost:52620/");
var hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");
if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
{
    await connection.Start();
}
await hub.Invoke("SendNotifications", Id.ToString());
```

**Web application**

```
public class TestHub : Hub
{
    public void SendNotifications(string Id)
    { }
}
```

But notification not appended in application. What have I missed in this ?

It returns method not found exception.

[image]

**Note:** I am using different solution file and hosted separately in iis in same server for web api and web application site

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41504667/group-chat-signal-r-with-web-api/41505473#41505473 Check the answer here it could help

Comment: I am using different solution for web api and web application site.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. Since you are recreating connection for every call for this API if the apps are on the same server you can access with a static method if not use the call from client directly SignalR is not intended for server to server communication.